# If Statement: Return dynamic output as "value if true" based on multiple potential cell inputs

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, dynamic

I have an ifs statement that is checking for 1 out of X keywords. Depending on which keyword is in there, it returns any value. Boiled down its something like this:

```
ifs(
Cell1="Text1",0,
Cell1="Text2",0.5,
Cell1="Text3",1
)
```

So currently I either get **0**, **0.5** or **1** as an output. Per *if statement* one value gets returned.

I am looking for a way to just have one *if statement* checking the *Cell* and return a value based on what we find. To explain the idea with wrong syntax:

```
if(
Cell1="Text1"or"Text2"or"Text3"
return:
0 if its "Tex1" or
0.5 if its "Text2" or
1 if its "Text2"
)
```

I am struggling with the syntax and logic behind it. Here is the actual formula I am currently using, I hope that helps. Without context this might seem overly complicated. My main point is to have these three statements combined into one to shorten the formula as much as possible.

```
ifs(
VLOOKUP($A2, Sheet1!$A$3:$W, index(filter(arrayformula(column(Sheet1!$A$1:$1)),Sheet1!$A$1:$1=E$1),,1),false)="text1",0,
VLOOKUP($A2, Sheet1!$A$3:$W, index(filter(arrayformula(column(Sheet1!$A$1:$1)),Sheet1!$A$1:$1=E$1),,1),false)="text2",0.5,
VLOOKUP($A2, Sheet1!$A$3:$W, index(filter(arrayformula(column(Sheet1!$A$1:$1)),Sheet1!$A$1:$1=E$1),,1),false)="text3",1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following [SWITCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013690) formula

```
=SWITCH(A2,"A",1,"B",0.5,"C",0,"")
```

Bear in mind that in your case `A2` would be your `VLOOKUP` formula and `A`, `B`, `C` would be your `text1`, `text2` and `text3` values.
The last part `""` in the formula will return as blank any value that doesn't meet your conditions.

```
=SWITCH(vlookupFormula,"text1",1,"text2",0.5,"text3",0,"")
```

*(please -as always- adjust formula according to your ranges and locale)*